# Bootstrap datatable using python

Tags: django, python-2.7, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am doing one project using bootstrap and django framework with pycharm editor. I have one form called candidates details form. After entering values in that form it should be displayed in home page data table so I am not getting how to do that as am new to django and bootstrap

This is my model.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

CATEGORY = (
    ('INTERNAL', 1),
    ('EXTERNAL', 2)
)

CANDIDATE_STATUS = (
    ('SELECTED', 1),
    ('REJECTED', 2),
    ('ON-HOLD', 3)
)

CANDIDATE_RESULT = (
    ('CLEARED', 1),
    ('REJECTED', 2)
)

class UserRegister(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    password = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)


class CandidateSkills(models.Model):
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)


class BUDetails(models.Model):
    bu_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    bu_head = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)


class CandidateDetails(models.Model):
    candidate_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    current_company = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(CandidateSkills, null=True)
    experience = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    notice_period = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY, max_length=100, null=True)
    email_id = models.EmailField(null=True)
    mobile_no = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True)
    telephone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True)
    bus_unit = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking and sounds as though it would be too broad... What have you tried? What do the models you've shown here have to do directly with your question?

Comment: Also, have you tried looking at the documentation, about how forms and model connect in Django.

Comment: You can use [django-tables2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2)

Comment: please include your HTML file too

Comment: I cant add my html page because its too long to upload

Comment: I cant add my html page because its too long to upload